# Date axis not converting to continuous axis for a forward curve chart

Tags: datetime, line

I'm trying to create a forward curve for a certain commodity, the x-axis is a date axis but it is not converting to a continuous axis so the ticks are without any gaps.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
geom_line(data=dataset,aes(x=dataset$'Fut_Date', y=Value,group=dataset$'Trading_Date'),linewidth=0.3, alpha=0.2) + 
geom_point(data=dataset,aes(x=dataset$'Trading_Date', y=Spot),size=0.2,  color="red")  + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))   + labs(title = "PTA Forward Curves", x = "Dates", y = "PTA Prices (RMB)")
```

[image]

This is the chart I'm trying to make.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.